# Error in Keras NLP model training: matrix type cannot be converted to python

Tags: r, dataframe, keras, nlp

I am trying to create an NLP model (and eventually a graph of semantic similarity) of some text data.

Here's what my data looks like:

```
topic_model # a tibble of 2 <chr> columns
```

[image]

And here's where I try to train the model and run into an error:

```
model %>%
  fit_generator(
    skipgrams_generator(topic_model, tokenizer, skip_window, negative_samples), 
    steps_per_epoch = 100000, epochs = 5
    )
```

This code results in the following error:

```
"Error occurred in generator: Matrix type cannot be converted to python (only integer, numeric, complex, logical, and character matrixes can be converted

Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords): RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration"
```

What's the problem here? Do I need to convert the tibble to a matrix of characters?

See my full notebook here: https://www.kaggle.com/vintners/modal-backgrounds-nlp

Comment: To be able to better help please run topic_model.summary() and show the result here.

Comment: @Experience_In_AI see the kaggle notebook & the screenshot above - topic_model is a tibble. It does not have the .summary() function

Answer (score 2):

Do you get the same error if you pass "topic_model" as a vector instead of a tibble?

E.g.

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(stringdist)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidytext)
library(sjmisc)
library(vroom)
library(keras)
library(reticulate)
library(purrr)


dataset <- vroom("texts.csv", delim = ",")
# Data cleaning: filter by scenario, eliminate stop words 
topic_model <- dataset %>% filter(startsWith(scenario_id_fr, "2_")) # start with scenario 2 as a test
unnested <- topic_model %>% unnest_tokens(word, text) # separating by words
unnested <- unnested %>% anti_join(stop_words) # getting rid of stop words ("the", "and", etc.)
topic_model <- unnested %>% group_by(scenario_id_fr) %>%
  summarize(text = str_c(word, collapse = " ")) %>%
  ungroup()  # rejoining words back into strings

# Create text vector ("text_data")
text_data <- topic_model$text

# prepare for NLP with keras 
tokenizer <- text_tokenizer(num_words = 20000) # create token for 20,000 most common words in data
tokenizer %>% fit_text_tokenizer(text_data)

# define a generator function for model training 
skipgrams_generator <- function(text, tokenizer, window_size, negative_samples) {
  gen <- texts_to_sequences_generator(tokenizer, sample(text))
  function() {
    skip <- generator_next(gen) %>%
      skipgrams(
        vocabulary_size = tokenizer$num_words, 
        window_size = window_size, 
        negative_samples = 1
      )
    x <- transpose(skip$couples) %>% map(. %>% unlist %>% as.matrix(ncol = 1))
    y <- skip$labels %>% as.matrix(ncol = 1)
    list(x, y)
  }
}

# define variables 
embedding_size <- 128  # Dimension of the embedding vector.
skip_window <- 5       # How many words to consider left and right.
num_sampled <- 1       # Number of negative examples to sample for each word.
input_target <- layer_input(shape = 1)
input_context <- layer_input(shape = 1)

# create the embedding matrix
embedding <- layer_embedding(
  input_dim = tokenizer$num_words + 1, 
  output_dim = embedding_size, 
  input_length = 1, 
  name = "embedding"
)

target_vector <- input_target %>% 
  embedding() %>% 
  layer_flatten()

context_vector <- input_context %>%
  embedding() %>%
  layer_flatten()

# use dot product to calculate text similarity 
dot_product <- layer_dot(list(target_vector, context_vector), axes = 1)
output <- layer_dense(dot_product, units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")

# create and run the model 
model <- keras_model(list(input_target, input_context), output)
model %>% compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = "adam")

model %>%
  keras::fit_generator(
    skipgrams_generator(text_data, tokenizer, skip_window, num_sampled), 
    steps_per_epoch = 100000, epochs = 5, verbose = 1
  )
```

On my laptop I ran into problems with larger `steps_per_epoch` values (no GPU), but the fit completed successfully using smaller values:

```
model %>%
  keras::fit(
    skipgrams_generator(text_data, tokenizer, skip_window, num_sampled), 
    steps_per_epoch = 1, epochs = 10
  )
#>Epoch 1/10
#>1/1 [==============================] - 0s 50ms/step - loss: 0.6879
#>Epoch 2/10
#>1/1 [==============================] - 0s 52ms/step - loss: 0.6939
#>Epoch 3/10
#>1/1 [==============================] - 0s 54ms/step - loss: 0.6865
#>Epoch 4/10
#>1/1 [==============================] - 1s 538ms/step - loss: 0.6907
#>Epoch 5/10
#>1/1 [==============================] - 0s 44ms/step - loss: 0.6945
#>Epoch 6/10
#>1/1 [==============================] - 0s 40ms/step - loss: 0.6854
#>Epoch 7/10
#>1/1 [==============================] - 0s 43ms/step - loss: 0.6917
#>Epoch 8/10
#>1/1 [==============================] - 0s 41ms/step - loss: 0.6842
#>Epoch 9/10
#>1/1 [==============================] - 0s 42ms/step - loss: 0.6796
#>Epoch 10/10
#>1/1 [==============================] - 0s 43ms/step - loss: 0.6769
```

[image: example.png]

And for further exploring the model weights:

```
embedding_matrix <- get_weights(model)[[1]]

words <- data_frame(
  word = names(tokenizer$word_index), 
  id = as.integer(unlist(tokenizer$word_index))
)
words <- words %>%
  filter(id <= tokenizer$num_words) %>%
  arrange(id)

embedded_matrix <- embedding_matrix[1:239,1:128]
row.names(embedded_matrix) <- c(words$word)

#install.packages("text2vec")
library(text2vec)
find_similar_words <- function(word, embedded_matrix, n = 5) {
  similarities <- embedded_matrix[word, , drop = FALSE] %>%
    sim2(embedded_matrix, y = ., method = "cosine")
  similarities[,1] %>% sort(decreasing = TRUE) %>% head(n)
}
find_similar_words("call", embedded_matrix)
#>     call    pickup    forget     offer      move 
#>1.0000000 0.2828739 0.2228014 0.2153007 0.1994119
```

Obviously this result indicates the need for waaaay more training, but I think this shows a potential solution to at least one of your problems.